# How to await a user control?

Tags: uwp

The ContentDialog is pretty enough to do all tasks. But for some reasons, I want to use a Usercontrol and await for it to finish, to return the results. In content dialogs, we use ShowAsync method. But I am clueless how to achieve this in usercontrol.

```
LoginUserControl login = new LoginUserControl();
await login.ShowAsync(); //How to achieve this?
if (login.EnteredPassword == "1234") {}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use UserControl instead of ContentDialog? Are you willing to use the ContentDialog to pass the UserControl to its content property?In this case,you can still use the feature of the ContentDialog and show your UserControl.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT The background overlay around/behind the content dialog does not fit to my UI. I want to occupy the entire background of the calling page, w/o bg. This is one of the reasons. Moreover I am eager to know how to implement the ShowAsync to UserControls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Popup to achieve the effect of ContentDialog.

.xaml(UserControl):

```
<Grid>
        <Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.4"/>​
        <Grid Background="White" Width="150" Height="180" >​
            ......
          <Button x:Name="OKButton" Click="Button_Click">Sure</Button>
        </Grid>​
</Grid>
```

.cs(UserControl):

```
public sealed partial class MyCustomContentDialog : UserControl
{
    public Action<String> hideType;
    Popup hostPopup;
    internal event ClickButtonEventHandler ClickButtonEvent;
    public MyCustomContentDialog()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        EnteredPassword = MyName.Text;
        hostPopup = new Popup();
        hostPopup.Child = this;
        this.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
        this.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
    }


    public void Show()
    {
        hostPopup.IsOpen = true;

    }
    public void Hide(String buttonType)
    {
        hostPopup.IsOpen = false;
        hideType?.Invoke(buttonType);
    }

    public String EnteredPassword { get; set; }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Hide("Sure");

    }
}
```

When you want to pop up the userControl:

```
MyCustomContentDialog userControl = new MyCustomContentDialog();
userControl.Show();
userControl.hideType+= (_s) =>
        {
            if (_s == "Sure")
            {
                //do something
            }
            else {
                //do something else
            }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems a good solution. But how to await for ok/cancel button clicks?

Comment: Click ok/cancel button and when you have done what you need to do,you can call to the Hide() method to close the usercontrol.

Comment: No. The await userControl.Show(); does not await for/ listen to ok-cancel button clicks. It can await only for the showAsync method. We can implement custom event handlers with await method for ok-cancel buttons. but, they will fire & await separately, not on the await userControl.ShowAsync() code line, as we do in dialog control. Hope I have explained as I could.

Comment: You can use Action Injection.When you call the Hide method and trigger the Action, you can receive the type of button passed in the main view.Then you can do the appropriate action based on the button type.I have edited my answer,you can try it.

Comment: Yes. Achieved the effect of await using Action injection. Great idea. Though it is a simple thing for you, it is really useful for me in many scenarios, wherever I don't prefer ContentDialog. Thank you so much!

Comment: For you kind note: Please format your code. Since I had to rewrite the same code in my Visual studio, I couldn't copy paste. o/w VS didn't compile, saying some error, in text format/encoding or something else.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder, I will pay more attention later.